# Round double values and cast as integers

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rounding

I have a data frame in PySpark like below.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
        [(0.0, 0.2, 3.45631),
         (0.4, 1.4, 2.82945),
         (0.5, 1.9, 7.76261),
         (0.6, 0.9, 2.76790),
         (1.2, 1.0, 9.87984)],
         ["col1", "col2", "col3"])

df.show()
+----+----+-------+ 
|col1|col2|   col3|
+----+----+-------+
| 0.0| 0.2|3.45631| 
| 0.4| 1.4|2.82945|
| 0.5| 1.9|7.76261| 
| 0.6| 0.9| 2.7679| 
| 1.2| 1.0|9.87984| 
+----+----+-------+

# round 'col3' in a new column:
df2 = df.withColumn("col4", func.round(df["col3"], 2))
df2.show()

+----+----+-------+----+
|col1|col2|   col3|col4|
+----+----+-------+----+
| 0.0| 0.2|3.45631|3.46|
| 0.4| 1.4|2.82945|2.83|
| 0.5| 1.9|7.76261|7.76|
| 0.6| 0.9| 2.7679|2.77|
| 1.2| 1.0|9.87984|9.88|
+----+----+-------+----+
```

In the above data frame `col4` is `double`. Now I want to convert `col4` as `Integer`

```
df2 = df.withColumn("col4", func.round(df["col3"], 2).cast('integer'))

+----+----+-------+----+
|col1|col2|   col3|col4|
+----+----+-------+----+
| 0.0| 0.2|3.45631|   3|
| 0.4| 1.4|2.82945|   2|
| 0.5| 1.9|7.76261|   7|
| 0.6| 0.9| 2.7679|   2|
| 1.2| 1.0|9.87984|   9|
+----+----+-------+----+
```

But I want to round the `col4` values to nearest

`expected result`

```
+----+----+-------+----+
|col1|col2|   col3|col4|
+----+----+-------+----+
| 0.0| 0.2|3.45631|   3|
| 0.4| 1.4|2.82945|   3|
| 0.5| 1.9|7.76261|   8|
| 0.6| 0.9| 2.7679|   3|
| 1.2| 1.0|9.87984|  10|
+----+----+-------+----+
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should use the `round` function and then cast to integer type. However, do not use a second argument to the `round` function. By using 2 there it will round to 2 decimal places, the `cast` to integer will then **round down** to the nearest number.

Instead use:

```
df2 = df.withColumn("col4", func.round(df["col3"]).cast('integer'))
```

Comment: Just a small doubt Here when we round `1.5` it becomes `2` right. is there a way where we can `round` `0.4` to `1` and so on

Comment: @Question_bank: Yes, that is possible. Instead of `round` you will want to use the `ceil` function to always round up.

Comment: @Shaido answer was to the point! I had the same question and I  understand that with round in 2 decimal places, you round in 2 decimals (e.x 2.891 --> 2.89) and then you truncate the digits with integer casting. On the other hand, when you don't use decimal places, it rounds in 0 decimal (e.x 2.891 --> 3.0)  and then with integer casting you have your expected result.

Comment: Just take care with negative numbers. -14.05 becomes -14 when you use ceil().